# how to write subquery in hibernate with full join

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate i want to convert below query in hibernate

```sql
Select a.* from ((select b.* from B b) full 
    join (select c.* from C c) on b.id=c.id) a where a.somecoulumn=condition
```

Comment: what you have tried ?????

Comment: I created one function as follows public List getList(String hql) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        List list = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            list = session.createQuery(hql).list();
            tx.commit();
            return list;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

Comment: and tried to write hql but it gives syntax error near "("

Answer (score 0):

Use createSqlQuery instead of createQuery ..

```
    public List getList(String sql) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        List list = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            list = session.createSQLQuery(sql).list();
            tx.commit();
            return list;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It Works I also thought to work using Native SQL. But how can i achieve same thing using HQL? because Native Sql may trouble, it will become database dependent

Comment: Try using Criteria in hibernate.It is easy than HQL